# Average values in a column across several rows for each unique value in another column in MS Access

Tags: ms-access, average

I have query which produces a result like this:

```
ID | Area | Price
1 | A | 10
2 | A | 15
3 | A | 10
4 | B | 20
5 | B | 15
```

The query linked two tables one with ID and Area, another with ID and Price. I want change my query to average the price field for each area so I would end up with:

```
Area | Price
A | 11.6
B | 17.5
```

I have multiple price fields which I would like to average in the same format.

I'm using MS Access 2010.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve your desired result by simply basing your "averaging query" on your existing query. Say your existing query was saved as `AreaAndPriceByID`. Just create a new query like this:

```
SELECT Area, AVG(Price) AS AvgPrice
FROM AreaAndPriceByID
GROUP BY Area
```

If you want to round the averages to one decimal place you can use `Round(AVG(Price), 1)` instead.